# pstricks \rput not working

Tags: pstricks

When I process this file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}        
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid,framesep=0pt](6,3)
        \psdot(3,2)     % The dot appears at 3,2
        \rput(3,2){X}   % The X is expected at 3,2 but appears at 0,1
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

the \psdot is positioned correctly but the X appears at (0,0) instead of (3,2).
Similar questions exist but are not answered.  My example is simple and complete and I hope this helps identify the problem.  I normally use XeLaTeX to process my documents but I can't get this example to work using any other command chain I know of.  My operating system is Debian 11.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I do not have this problem.

Comment: Testing this on Overleaf didn't show this issue on TeX Live 2021, 2020 or 2019 (Then I stopped testing since Debian 11 should ship at least TeX Live 2020 anyway)

Comment: @Cliff You might want to look at [this thread on the pstricks mailing list from around the same time your Debian's TeX Live is from describing and fixing a similar issue](https://tug.org/pipermail/pstricks/2021/011245.html).

Comment: There was a problem with `xdvipdfmx` and `\rput` some time ago. But it was fixed in 2020. Can you provide the `dvi` file for download, created with a `latex` run?

Comment: @user187802 I feel silly asking this but how do I upload a file in StackExchange?  Anyway i doubt it would help.  I ran `latex` on my test file and when I view the dvi I see nothing but the `X`  from `\rput(3,2){X}` in the example and the page number.  Not even the grids or dots or anything else appears.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger - I read through the thread and tried the `dvipdfmx.cfg` file that was suggested as the fix.  Installing that configuration didn't break anything, but it didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: @CliffN: You shouldn't view the dvi-file. View the ps or pdf file.  And you cannot upload a file to StackExchange but maybe you can save it elsewhere, where we can download it.